# iOS 9 upgrade question

Tags: ios

Quick question, if you are still in iOS8 in your iPhone and it shows software upgrade in the settings, which version will it upgrade to 9.0 or to the latest 9.2?

Answer (score 3):

The latest, currently 9.2
It ought to drop the older version & download the new, as it's released.

If that failed for any reason, then it would fetch the latest immediately [or soon] after you upgrade.

The simplest & safest method is always to do it via iTunes, assuming you already have iTunes linked to the phone.

- Connect the phone
- Download the update but don't install it.
- Sync the phone with iTunes.
- Switch to the Apps tab & get all pending updates.
- Sync again.
- Backup.
- Disconnect & reconnect, then when it asks, run the update.

Answer (score 0):

It will upgrade to the latest one available for your device. My device too is on 8 and it will be upgraded to 9.1 directly.

[image]

Hope this helps.

Comment: 9.2 is the latest, so yours hasn't picked up the new version yet. Neither has my iPad, so I guess it takes some time to roll out to everyone.

Comment: @Tetsujin Yup they roll out the updates in groups, few at a time.